# Merge into table with parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, merge, sql-insert

I'm stuck and i know that this is easier than i think it is.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
SELECT ID , NAME , CITY FROM TEMP
```

[image]

I have created a Merge statement with Parameters that should insert a new row if ID and City does not already exist

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TMP]

@ID INT, 
@City NVARCHAR(50) 

AS

MERGE TEMP AS TARGET
USING 
(
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    CITY
FROM TEMP

) AS SOURCE 
    ON [TARGET].[ID]=  @ID AND [TARGET].[City] = @City 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT 
(   
    [ID],
    [NAME],
    [CITY]

)
VALUES
(
   @ID,
   [SOURCE].[NAME],
   @City

);
```

I know im doing something wrong here because ALLA the records gets effected.

I would like a outcome of this (if @ID = '1' and @City = 'New York')

[image]

I would like to use a MERGE() and not "Insert into" if possible.

Comment: If you call it with `@ActivityID = 1` and `@City = 'New York'`, how should the engine know you want it to insert only `'Steve'` for `Name`?

Comment: i have updated the question [@]Activity should be [@]ID....

Comment: My question still stands...how should the engine know you want to insert `(ID, City) = (1, 'New York')` **ONLY** for the name Steve? Is it because the other rows where `ID = 1` the name is Steve?

Comment: Yes becasue i do not want to create a new parameter where i should say "steve" for name column. I might be thinking wrong here(?)

Comment: Then the structure is wrong as far as relational databases go, it should be something like `Person (ID, Name)` and then you should have only a reference to that table as `TEMP (PersonID, City)`. However if it'll always be the same name for one ID, I'll whip something up in the answer section in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like to say the consistency of a solution like this isn't good at all.

However, in order for it to work as you described in the comments, change the code like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TMP]

@ID INT, 
@City NVARCHAR(50) 

AS

MERGE TEMP AS TARGET
USING 
(
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    CITY
FROM TEMP

) AS SOURCE 
    ON [TARGET].[ID]= @ID AND [TARGET].[City] = @City

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT 
(   
    [ID],
    [NAME],
    [CITY]

)
VALUES
(
   @ID,
   (SELECT TOP(1) t.Name FROM TEMP t WHERE t.ID = @ID),
   @City

);
```

Should do the trick.

Also, I'm not sure why you want to use `MERGE` only, but this would be a good candidate for `IF NOT EXISTS ... INSERT INTO` like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TMP]

@ID INT, 
@City NVARCHAR(50) 

AS

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM TEMP WHERE ID = @ID AND City = @City)
  INSERT INTO TEMP(ID, City, Name)
     VALUES (@ID, @City, (SELECT TOP(1) Name FROM TEMP WHERE ID = @ID));
```

Comment: I have updated the pictures of what i'm after, Does this make more sense or are your exampel still the same?

Comment: The code should still work. I also aded another way of doing it

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was after. Might not be the best approach but it works :)

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the code first approach you simply use  [Index(IsUnique = true)] try this.Ex:

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```